# Map parameter to label

Tags: jenkins

I have a pipeline parameterized by `env` which takes specific values shown below. The parameter is used in the script and cannot change. But the admin tells me that the labels for the agent have to depend on the parameter `env` and another fixed one (e.G. `LABELX`).

The problem I encounter is that, while the script requires exactly the values shown below, the label for the agent is not always `${params.env}`, but in one case there's a mapping/translation to be made.

This is the extremely reduced groovy script:

```
pipeline {
    agent {label "${params.env} && LABELX"}
    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'env',
            choices: ['development', 'staging', 'production'],
        )
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Process') {
            steps {
                sh """
                # use ${params.env} in bash script
                """"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The mapping I need is as follows:

| env | label |
| --- | --- |
| development | development |
| staging | test |
| production | production |

How can I replace the parameter `staging` with the label `test` before choosing an agent? I cannot do that in a script, because scripts are run by agents... I have to somehow do this before, inside the `${params.env}` maybe. Or do I need an additional parameter (`params.label`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve it is to create a constant label mapping before your pipeline, and then use it in your pipeline to retrieve the needed value.
Something like:

```groovy
LABELS = ['development':'development', 'staging':'test', 'production':'production']

pipeline {
    agent {
       label "${LABELS[params.env]} && LABELX"
    }
    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'env',
            choices: ['development', 'staging', 'production'],
        )
    }
    stages {
        stage('Process') {
            steps {
                sh """
                # use ${params.env} in bash script
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, it is not recommended to call your parameter `env` as it may override or collide in some cases with the default `env` map that contains all the environment parameters of the job, including those defined in the environment directive.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for! Later, when I'll have access to machine, I'll try it. I already accept this as the answer.